# How to code dropdowns that depend on other dropdowns - using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I have two Flutter dropdowns. The first loads a list of universities from a database and works perfectly. The second loads campuses for the selected university from a database.

At the moment I am using setState() from the onChanged() function of the university dropdown which works 80% of the time. The other 20% seems to be caused by a slow network whereby the dropdown hasn't had time to fill before the screen refreshes, leaving it empty. If the university dropdown is clicked once, twice or three times the campuses dropdown will usually fill. Here is the loading code (where loadDatabaseSubTable() fills the campus dropdown:

```
 Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(width: 1),
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: kContainerPaddingHorizontal,
          vertical: kContainerPaddingVertical),
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
       hint: Text('Select the Institution'),
        value: selectedInstitute,
        underline: Container(
          height: 0,
        ),
        onChanged: (String value) {
          // Use setState() to load next dropdown
          if (institutionBefore != value) {
              setState(() {
              // Get matching campuses
              dropCampus = [];
              campusBuild.institutionId = shInstitutionId;
              campusBuild.campusId = '';
              loadDatabaseSubTable(
                  tableName: 'sa_campus_by_institute',
                  listVariable: dropCampus,
                  object: campusBuild);
              //
              selectedInstitute = value;
            });
          }
        },
        items: dropInstitution.map((String description) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: description,
            child: Text(
              description,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    ),
```

Is the above method the correct way of going about this?  If so how can I make sure the refresh doesn't occur before the dropdown has filled?

Or is it better to use a FutureBuilder to handle it?

I had thought to load all the campuses for all universities into memory first - but for an Android App. this seems like overkill on bandwidth usage.

I have another screen which has 6 dropdowns, each dependent on the previous one - using a FutureBuilder for each seems like a very untidy way of processing the dropdowns. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that loadDatabaseSubTable is async and you're not waiting for it finish so by the time it fetches the data your setState would have been executed.

You need to change the `onChanged` to be async:

```
onChanged: (String value) async {
```

and then await the loadDatabaseSubTable:

```
await loadDatabaseSubTable(
  tableName: 'sa_campus_by_institute',
  listVariable: dropCampus,
  object: campusBuild);
```

See also

- https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: Thanks @Sami, after doing some thorough testing this code is holding up and doing exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In example code, after choose first dropdown `state`, there is 5 seconds delay to **simulate** retrieve items of second dropdown `Local government area`  
Step 1: You can in `onChanged` to set second dropdown and use `async await` to load database table

```
DropdownButton<String>(
            ...
            onChanged: (value) => _onSelectedState(value),
```

Step 2: You can set `bool _isLoading` to `true` and show  `CircularProgressIndicator()` when data is not ready

```
_isLoading
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : DropdownButton<String>(
```

Step 3: After data is ready set `bool _isLoading` to `false`

```
setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
```

code snippet

```
void _onSelectedState(String value) async {
    setState(() {
      _selectedLGA = "Choose ..";
      _selectedState = value;
      _lgas = ["Choose .."];
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    _lgas = List.from(_lgas)..addAll(await repo.getLocalByState(value));

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Repository repo = Repository();

  List<String> _states = ["Choose a state"];
  List<String> _lgas = ["Choose .."];
  String _selectedState = "Choose a state";
  String _selectedLGA = "Choose ..";
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _states = List.from(_states)..addAll(repo.getStates());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("STATES MULTI DROPDOWN"),
        elevation: 0.1,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 30),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              DropdownButton<String>(
                isExpanded: true,
                items: _states.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: dropDownStringItem,
                    child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) => _onSelectedState(value),
                value: _selectedState,
              ),
              _isLoading
                  ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                  : DropdownButton<String>(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      items: _lgas.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: dropDownStringItem,
                          child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      // onChanged: (value) => print(value),
                      onChanged: (value) => _onSelectedLGA(value),
                      value: _selectedLGA,
                    ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onSelectedState(String value) async {
    setState(() {
      _selectedLGA = "Choose ..";
      _selectedState = value;
      _lgas = ["Choose .."];
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    _lgas = List.from(_lgas)..addAll(await repo.getLocalByState(value));

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  void _onSelectedLGA(String value) {
    setState(() => _selectedLGA = value);
  }
}

class Repository {
  // http://locationsng-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/lgas
  // test() => _nigeria.map((map) => StateModel.fromJson(map));
  List<Map> getAll() => _nigeria;

  /*getLocalByState(String state) => _nigeria
      .map((map) => StateModel.fromJson(map))
      .where((item) => item.state == state)
      .map((item) => item.lgas)
      .expand((i) => i)
      .toList();*/

  Future<List<String>> getLocalByState(String state) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      print("Future.delayed");
    });

    return Future.value(_nigeria
        .map((map) => StateModel.fromJson(map))
        .where((item) => item.state == state)
        .map((item) => item.lgas)
        .expand((i) => i)
        .toList());
  }
  // _nigeria.where((list) => list['state'] == state);
  // .map((item) => item['lgas'])
  // .expand((i) => i)
  // .toList();

  List<String> getStates() => _nigeria
      .map((map) => StateModel.fromJson(map))
      .map((item) => item.state)
      .toList();
  // _nigeria.map((item) => item['state'].toString()).toList();

  List _nigeria = [
    {
      "state": "Adamawa",
      "alias": "adamawa",
      "lgas": [
        "Demsa",
        "Fufure",
        "Ganye",
        "Gayuk",
        "Gombi",
        "Grie",
        "Hong",
        "Jada",
        "Larmurde",
        "Madagali",
        "Maiha",
        "Mayo Belwa",
        "Michika",
        "Mubi North",
        "Mubi South",
        "Numan",
        "Shelleng",
        "Song",
        "Toungo",
        "Yola North",
        "Yola South"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Akwa Ibom",
      "alias": "akwa_ibom",
      "lgas": [
        "Abak",
        "Eastern Obolo",
        "Eket",
        "Esit Eket",
        "Essien Udim",
        "Etim Ekpo",
        "Etinan",
        "Ibeno",
        "Ibesikpo Asutan",
        "Ibiono-Ibom",
        "Ikot Abasi",
        "Ika",
        "Ikono",
        "Ikot Ekpene",
        "Ini",
        "Mkpat-Enin",
        "Itu",
        "Mbo",
        "Nsit-Atai",
        "Nsit-Ibom",
        "Nsit-Ubium",
        "Obot Akara",
        "Okobo",
        "Onna",
        "Oron",
        "Udung-Uko",
        "Ukanafun",
        "Oruk Anam",
        "Uruan",
        "Urue-Offong/Oruko",
        "Uyo"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Anambra",
      "alias": "anambra",
      "lgas": [
        "Aguata",
        "Anambra East",
        "Anaocha",
        "Awka North",
        "Anambra West",
        "Awka South",
        "Ayamelum",
        "Dunukofia",
        "Ekwusigo",
        "Idemili North",
        "Idemili South",
        "Ihiala",
        "Njikoka",
        "Nnewi North",
        "Nnewi South",
        "Ogbaru",
        "Onitsha North",
        "Onitsha South",
        "Orumba North",
        "Orumba South",
        "Oyi"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Ogun",
      "alias": "ogun",
      "lgas": [
        "Abeokuta North",
        "Abeokuta South",
        "Ado-Odo/Ota",
        "Egbado North",
        "Ewekoro",
        "Egbado South",
        "Ijebu North",
        "Ijebu East",
        "Ifo",
        "Ijebu Ode",
        "Ijebu North East",
        "Imeko Afon",
        "Ikenne",
        "Ipokia",
        "Odeda",
        "Obafemi Owode",
        "Odogbolu",
        "Remo North",
        "Ogun Waterside",
        "Shagamu"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Ondo",
      "alias": "ondo",
      "lgas": [
        "Akoko North-East",
        "Akoko North-West",
        "Akoko South-West",
        "Akoko South-East",
        "Akure North",
        "Akure South",
        "Ese Odo",
        "Idanre",
        "Ifedore",
        "Ilaje",
        "Irele",
        "Ile Oluji/Okeigbo",
        "Odigbo",
        "Okitipupa",
        "Ondo West",
        "Ose",
        "Ondo East",
        "Owo"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Rivers",
      "alias": "rivers",
      "lgas": [
        "Abua/Odual",
        "Ahoada East",
        "Ahoada West",
        "Andoni",
        "Akuku-Toru",
        "Asari-Toru",
        "Bonny",
        "Degema",
        "Emuoha",
        "Eleme",
        "Ikwerre",
        "Etche",
        "Gokana",
        "Khana",
        "Obio/Akpor",
        "Ogba/Egbema/Ndoni",
        "Ogu/Bolo",
        "Okrika",
        "Omuma",
        "Opobo/Nkoro",
        "Oyigbo",
        "Port Harcourt",
        "Tai"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Bauchi",
      "alias": "bauchi",
      "lgas": [
        "Alkaleri",
        "Bauchi",
        "Bogoro",
        "Damban",
        "Darazo",
        "Dass",
        "Gamawa",
        "Ganjuwa",
        "Giade",
        "Itas/Gadau",
        "Jama'are",
        "Katagum",
        "Kirfi",
        "Misau",
        "Ningi",
        "Shira",
        "Tafawa Balewa",
        "Toro",
        "Warji",
        "Zaki"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Benue",
      "alias": "benue",
      "lgas": [
        "Agatu",
        "Apa",
        "Ado",
        "Buruku",
        "Gboko",
        "Guma",
        "Gwer East",
        "Gwer West",
        "Katsina-Ala",
        "Konshisha",
        "Kwande",
        "Logo",
        "Makurdi",
        "Obi",
        "Ogbadibo",
        "Ohimini",
        "Oju",
        "Okpokwu",
        "Oturkpo",
        "Tarka",
        "Ukum",
        "Ushongo",
        "Vandeikya"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Borno",
      "alias": "borno",
      "lgas": [
        "Abadam",
        "Askira/Uba",
        "Bama",
        "Bayo",
        "Biu",
        "Chibok",
        "Damboa",
        "Dikwa",
        "Guzamala",
        "Gubio",
        "Hawul",
        "Gwoza",
        "Jere",
        "Kaga",
        "Kala/Balge",
        "Konduga",
        "Kukawa",
        "Kwaya Kusar",
        "Mafa",
        "Magumeri",
        "Maiduguri",
        "Mobbar",
        "Marte",
        "Monguno",
        "Ngala",
        "Nganzai",
        "Shani"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Bayelsa",
      "alias": "bayelsa",
      "lgas": [
        "Brass",
        "Ekeremor",
        "Kolokuma/Opokuma",
        "Nembe",
        "Ogbia",
        "Sagbama",
        "Southern Ijaw",
        "Yenagoa"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Cross River",
      "alias": "cross_river",
      "lgas": [
        "Abi",
        "Akamkpa",
        "Akpabuyo",
        "Bakassi",
        "Bekwarra",
        "Biase",
        "Boki",
        "Calabar Municipal",
        "Calabar South",
        "Etung",
        "Ikom",
        "Obanliku",
        "Obubra",
        "Obudu",
        "Odukpani",
        "Ogoja",
        "Yakuur",
        "Yala"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Delta",
      "alias": "delta",
      "lgas": [
        "Aniocha North",
        "Aniocha South",
        "Bomadi",
        "Burutu",
        "Ethiope West",
        "Ethiope East",
        "Ika North East",
        "Ika South",
        "Isoko North",
        "Isoko South",
        "Ndokwa East",
        "Ndokwa West",
        "Okpe",
        "Oshimili North",
        "Oshimili South",
        "Patani",
        "Sapele",
        "Udu",
        "Ughelli North",
        "Ukwuani",
        "Ughelli South",
        "Uvwie",
        "Warri North",
        "Warri South",
        "Warri South West"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Ebonyi",
      "alias": "ebonyi",
      "lgas": [
        "Abakaliki",
        "Afikpo North",
        "Ebonyi",
        "Afikpo South",
        "Ezza North",
        "Ikwo",
        "Ezza South",
        "Ivo",
        "Ishielu",
        "Izzi",
        "Ohaozara",
        "Ohaukwu",
        "Onicha"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Edo",
      "alias": "edo",
      "lgas": [
        "Akoko-Edo",
        "Egor",
        "Esan Central",
        "Esan North-East",
        "Esan South-East",
        "Esan West",
        "Etsako Central",
        "Etsako East",
        "Etsako West",
        "Igueben",
        "Ikpoba Okha",
        "Orhionmwon",
        "Oredo",
        "Ovia North-East",
        "Ovia South-West",
        "Owan East",
        "Owan West",
        "Uhunmwonde"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Ekiti",
      "alias": "ekiti",
      "lgas": [
        "Ado Ekiti",
        "Efon",
        "Ekiti East",
        "Ekiti South-West",
        "Ekiti West",
        "Emure",
        "Gbonyin",
        "Ido Osi",
        "Ijero",
        "Ikere",
        "Ilejemeje",
        "Irepodun/Ifelodun",
        "Ikole",
        "Ise/Orun",
        "Moba",
        "Oye"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Enugu",
      "alias": "enugu",
      "lgas": [
        "Awgu",
        "Aninri",
        "Enugu East",
        "Enugu North",
        "Ezeagu",
        "Enugu South",
        "Igbo Etiti",
        "Igbo Eze North",
        "Igbo Eze South",
        "Isi Uzo",
        "Nkanu East",
        "Nkanu West",
        "Nsukka",
        "Udenu",
        "Oji River",
        "Uzo Uwani",
        "Udi"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Federal Capital Territory",
      "alias": "abuja",
      "lgas": [
        "Abaji",
        "Bwari",
        "Gwagwalada",
        "Kuje",
        "Kwali",
        "Municipal Area Council"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Gombe",
      "alias": "gombe",
      "lgas": [
        "Akko",
        "Balanga",
        "Billiri",
        "Dukku",
        "Funakaye",
        "Gombe",
        "Kaltungo",
        "Kwami",
        "Nafada",
        "Shongom",
        "Yamaltu/Deba"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Jigawa",
      "alias": "jigawa",
      "lgas": [
        "Auyo",
        "Babura",
        "Buji",
        "Biriniwa",
        "Birnin Kudu",
        "Dutse",
        "Gagarawa",
        "Garki",
        "Gumel",
        "Guri",
        "Gwaram",
        "Gwiwa",
        "Hadejia",
        "Jahun",
        "Kafin Hausa",
        "Kazaure",
        "Kiri Kasama",
        "Kiyawa",
        "Kaugama",
        "Maigatari",
        "Malam Madori",
        "Miga",
        "Sule Tankarkar",
        "Roni",
        "Ringim",
        "Yankwashi",
        "Taura"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Oyo",
      "alias": "oyo",
      "lgas": [
        "Afijio",
        "Akinyele",
        "Atiba",
        "Atisbo",
        "Egbeda",
        "Ibadan North",
        "Ibadan North-East",
        "Ibadan North-West",
        "Ibadan South-East",
        "Ibarapa Central",
        "Ibadan South-West",
        "Ibarapa East",
        "Ido",
        "Ibarapa North",
        "Irepo",
        "Iseyin",
        "Itesiwaju",
        "Iwajowa",
        "Kajola",
        "Lagelu",
        "Ogbomosho North",
        "Ogbomosho South",
        "Ogo Oluwa",
        "Olorunsogo",
        "Oluyole",
        "Ona Ara",
        "Orelope",
        "Ori Ire",
        "Oyo",
        "Oyo East",
        "Saki East",
        "Saki West",
        "Surulere Oyo State"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Imo",
      "alias": "imo",
      "lgas": [
        "Aboh Mbaise",
        "Ahiazu Mbaise",
        "Ehime Mbano",
        "Ezinihitte",
        "Ideato North",
        "Ideato South",
        "Ihitte/Uboma",
        "Ikeduru",
        "Isiala Mbano",
        "Mbaitoli",
        "Isu",
        "Ngor Okpala",
        "Njaba",
        "Nkwerre",
        "Nwangele",
        "Obowo",
        "Oguta",
        "Ohaji/Egbema",
        "Okigwe",
        "Orlu",
        "Orsu",
        "Oru East",
        "Oru West",
        "Owerri Municipal",
        "Owerri North",
        "Unuimo",
        "Owerri West"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Kaduna",
      "alias": "kaduna",
      "lgas": [
        "Birnin Gwari",
        "Chikun",
        "Giwa",
        "Ikara",
        "Igabi",
        "Jaba",
        "Jema'a",
        "Kachia",
        "Kaduna North",
        "Kaduna South",
        "Kagarko",
        "Kajuru",
        "Kaura",
        "Kauru",
        "Kubau",
        "Kudan",
        "Lere",
        "Makarfi",
        "Sabon Gari",
        "Sanga",
        "Soba",
        "Zangon Kataf",
        "Zaria"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Kebbi",
      "alias": "kebbi",
      "lgas": [
        "Aleiro",
        "Argungu",
        "Arewa Dandi",
        "Augie",
        "Bagudo",
        "Birnin Kebbi",
        "Bunza",
        "Dandi",
        "Fakai",
        "Gwandu",
        "Jega",
        "Kalgo",
        "Koko/Besse",
        "Maiyama",
        "Ngaski",
        "Shanga",
        "Suru",
        "Sakaba",
        "Wasagu/Danko",
        "Yauri",
        "Zuru"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Kano",
      "alias": "kano",
      "lgas": [
        "Ajingi",
        "Albasu",
        "Bagwai",
        "Bebeji",
        "Bichi",
        "Bunkure",
        "Dala",
        "Dambatta",
        "Dawakin Kudu",
        "Dawakin Tofa",
        "Doguwa",
        "Fagge",
        "Gabasawa",
        "Garko",
        "Garun Mallam",
        "Gezawa",
        "Gaya",
        "Gwale",
        "Gwarzo",
        "Kabo",
        "Kano Municipal",
        "Karaye",
        "Kibiya",
        "Kiru",
        "Kumbotso",
        "Kunchi",
        "Kura",
        "Madobi",
        "Makoda",
        "Minjibir",
        "Nasarawa",
        "Rano",
        "Rimin Gado",
        "Rogo",
        "Shanono",
        "Takai",
        "Sumaila",
        "Tarauni",
        "Tofa",
        "Tsanyawa",
        "Tudun Wada",
        "Ungogo",
        "Warawa",
        "Wudil"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Kogi",
      "alias": "kogi",
      "lgas": [
        "Ajaokuta",
        "Adavi",
        "Ankpa",
        "Bassa",
        "Dekina",
        "Ibaji",
        "Idah",
        "Igalamela Odolu",
        "Ijumu",
        "Kogi",
        "Kabba/Bunu",
        "Lokoja",
        "Ofu",
        "Mopa Muro",
        "Ogori/Magongo",
        "Okehi",
        "Okene",
        "Olamaboro",
        "Omala",
        "Yagba East",
        "Yagba West"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Osun",
      "alias": "osun",
      "lgas": [
        "Aiyedire",
        "Atakunmosa West",
        "Atakunmosa East",
        "Aiyedaade",
        "Boluwaduro",
        "Boripe",
        "Ife East",
        "Ede South",
        "Ife North",
        "Ede North",
        "Ife South",
        "Ejigbo",
        "Ife Central",
        "Ifedayo",
        "Egbedore",
        "Ila",
        "Ifelodun",
        "Ilesa East",
        "Ilesa West",
        "Irepodun",
        "Irewole",
        "Isokan",
        "Iwo",
        "Obokun",
        "Odo Otin",
        "Ola Oluwa",
        "Olorunda",
        "Oriade",
        "Orolu",
        "Osogbo"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Sokoto",
      "alias": "sokoto",
      "lgas": [
        "Gudu",
        "Gwadabawa",
        "Illela",
        "Isa",
        "Kebbe",
        "Kware",
        "Rabah",
        "Sabon Birni",
        "Shagari",
        "Silame",
        "Sokoto North",
        "Sokoto South",
        "Tambuwal",
        "Tangaza",
        "Tureta",
        "Wamako",
        "Wurno",
        "Yabo",
        "Binji",
        "Bodinga",
        "Dange Shuni",
        "Goronyo",
        "Gada"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Plateau",
      "alias": "plateau",
      "lgas": [
        "Bokkos",
        "Barkin Ladi",
        "Bassa",
        "Jos East",
        "Jos North",
        "Jos South",
        "Kanam",
        "Kanke",
        "Langtang South",
        "Langtang North",
        "Mangu",
        "Mikang",
        "Pankshin",
        "Qua'an Pan",
        "Riyom",
        "Shendam",
        "Wase"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Taraba",
      "alias": "taraba",
      "lgas": [
        "Ardo Kola",
        "Bali",
        "Donga",
        "Gashaka",
        "Gassol",
        "Ibi",
        "Jalingo",
        "Karim Lamido",
        "Kumi",
        "Lau",
        "Sardauna",
        "Takum",
        "Ussa",
        "Wukari",
        "Yorro",
        "Zing"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Yobe",
      "alias": "yobe",
      "lgas": [
        "Bade",
        "Bursari",
        "Damaturu",
        "Fika",
        "Fune",
        "Geidam",
        "Gujba",
        "Gulani",
        "Jakusko",
        "Karasuwa",
        "Machina",
        "Nangere",
        "Nguru",
        "Potiskum",
        "Tarmuwa",
        "Yunusari"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Zamfara",
      "alias": "zamfara",
      "lgas": [
        "Anka",
        "Birnin Magaji/Kiyaw",
        "Bakura",
        "Bukkuyum",
        "Bungudu",
        "Gummi",
        "Gusau",
        "Kaura Namoda",
        "Maradun",
        "Shinkafi",
        "Maru",
        "Talata Mafara",
        "Tsafe",
        "Zurmi"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Lagos",
      "alias": "lagos",
      "lgas": [
        "Agege",
        "Ajeromi-Ifelodun",
        "Alimosho",
        "Amuwo-Odofin",
        "Badagry",
        "Apapa",
        "Epe",
        "Eti Osa",
        "Ibeju-Lekki",
        "Ifako-Ijaiye",
        "Ikeja",
        "Ikorodu",
        "Kosofe",
        "Lagos Island",
        "Mushin",
        "Lagos Mainland",
        "Ojo",
        "Oshodi-Isolo",
        "Shomolu",
        "Surulere Lagos State"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Katsina",
      "alias": "katsina",
      "lgas": [
        "Bakori",
        "Batagarawa",
        "Batsari",
        "Baure",
        "Bindawa",
        "Charanchi",
        "Danja",
        "Dandume",
        "Dan Musa",
        "Daura",
        "Dutsi",
        "Dutsin Ma",
        "Faskari",
        "Funtua",
        "Ingawa",
        "Jibia",
        "Kafur",
        "Kaita",
        "Kankara",
        "Kankia",
        "Katsina",
        "Kurfi",
        "Kusada",
        "Mai'Adua",
        "Malumfashi",
        "Mani",
        "Mashi",
        "Matazu",
        "Musawa",
        "Rimi",
        "Sabuwa",
        "Safana",
        "Sandamu",
        "Zango"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Kwara",
      "alias": "kwara",
      "lgas": [
        "Asa",
        "Baruten",
        "Edu",
        "Ilorin East",
        "Ifelodun",
        "Ilorin South",
        "Ekiti Kwara State",
        "Ilorin West",
        "Irepodun",
        "Isin",
        "Kaiama",
        "Moro",
        "Offa",
        "Oke Ero",
        "Oyun",
        "Pategi"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Nasarawa",
      "alias": "nasarawa",
      "lgas": [
        "Akwanga",
        "Awe",
        "Doma",
        "Karu",
        "Keana",
        "Keffi",
        "Lafia",
        "Kokona",
        "Nasarawa Egon",
        "Nasarawa",
        "Obi",
        "Toto",
        "Wamba"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Niger",
      "alias": "niger",
      "lgas": [
        "Agaie",
        "Agwara",
        "Bida",
        "Borgu",
        "Bosso",
        "Chanchaga",
        "Edati",
        "Gbako",
        "Gurara",
        "Katcha",
        "Kontagora",
        "Lapai",
        "Lavun",
        "Mariga",
        "Magama",
        "Mokwa",
        "Mashegu",
        "Moya",
        "Paikoro",
        "Rafi",
        "Rijau",
        "Shiroro",
        "Suleja",
        "Tafa",
        "Wushishi"
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Abia",
      "alias": "abia",
      "lgas": [
        "Aba North",
        "Arochukwu",
        "Aba South",
        "Bende",
        "Isiala Ngwa North",
        "Ikwuano",
        "Isiala Ngwa South",
        "Isuikwuato",
        "Obi Ngwa",
        "Ohafia",
        "Osisioma",
        "Ugwunagbo",
        "Ukwa East",
        "Ukwa West",
        "Umuahia North",
        "Umuahia South",
        "Umu Nneochi"
      ]
    }
  ];
}

class StateModel {
  String state;
  String alias;
  List<String> lgas;

  StateModel({this.state, this.alias, this.lgas});

  StateModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    state = json['state'];
    alias = json['alias'];
    lgas = json['lgas'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['state'] = this.state;
    data['alias'] = this.alias;
    data['lgas'] = this.lgas;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chunhunghan for this thorough answer. The code does exactly what I want. However, setting an arbitrary delay of 5 seconds (or whatever) is not what I am looking for. This leaves the user 'hanging around' for a period of time that could be way in excess of the time taken to load records from the database. For that reason I have chosen Sami's answer above.

Comment: You misunderstand , 5 seconds is simulate your network delay. and without use of CircularProgressIndicator() , user will not know data is ready or not. he can still click second dropdown any time.

Comment: sorry I did not mentioned simulate keyword

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me @chunhunghan. But how can I use this same method if I want to do two dependent dropdown buttons of a list of car manufacturers(the first dropdown) and car models(the second dropdown)? But when I click on the model(the second) I want to be able to get the category of the model, so I can print and show if it's a car, truck, bus, and so on. Been having problems implementing that.

```
List _cars = [
    {
      "make": "Acura",
      "brand": [
        {"name": "CL", "category": "Coupe"},
        {"name": "ILX", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Integra", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Legend", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "MDX", "category": "SUV"},
        {"name": "NSX", "category": "Coupe"},
        {"name": "RDX", "category": "SUV"},
        {"name": "RL", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "RLX", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "RSX", "category": "Coupe"},
        {"name": "SLX", "category": "SUV"},
        {"name": "TL", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "TLX", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "TSX", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Vigor", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "ZDX", "category": "SUV"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "make": "Alfa Romeo",
      "brand": [
        {"name": "147", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "164", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "4C", "category": "Coupe"},
        {"name": "4C Spider", "category": "Convertible"},
        {"name": "Brera", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Giulia", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Giulietta", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "GT", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Mito", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Stelvio", "category": "SUV"},
      ]
    }
  ];
```

An example of the json file above.

```
class CarsModel {
  late String make;
  late List<Brand> brand;

  CarsModel({required this.make, required this.brand});

  CarsModel.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    make = json['make'];
    brand = json['brand'].map<Brand>((json) => Brand.fromJSON(json)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['make'] = this.make;
    data['brand'] = this.brand;
    return data;
  }
}

class Brand {
  late String name;
  late String category;

  Brand({required this.name, required this.category});

  Brand.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    category = json['category'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['category'] = this.category;

    return data;
  }
}
```

The model for the JSON file