# How to get the value of a dropdown that depend on other dropdown using Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I want to do two dependent dropdown buttons of a list of car manufacturers(the first dropdown) and car models/brands(the second dropdown)? But when I click on a brand(the second dropdown) I want to be able to get the category of the brand, so I can print and show if it's a car, truck, bus, and so on. Been having problems implementing that.

An example of the JSON file

```
List _cars = [
    {
      "make": "Acura",
      "brand": [
        {"name": "CL", "category": "Coupe"},
        {"name": "ILX", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Integra", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Legend", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "MDX", "category": "SUV"},
        {"name": "NSX", "category": "Coupe"},
        {"name": "RDX", "category": "SUV"},
        {"name": "RL", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "RLX", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "RSX", "category": "Coupe"},
        {"name": "SLX", "category": "SUV"},
        {"name": "TL", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "TLX", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "TSX", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Vigor", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "ZDX", "category": "SUV"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "make": "Alfa Romeo",
      "brand": [
        {"name": "147", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "164", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "4C", "category": "Coupe"},
        {"name": "4C Spider", "category": "Convertible"},
        {"name": "Brera", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Giulia", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Giulietta", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "GT", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Mito", "category": "Sedan"},
        {"name": "Stelvio", "category": "SUV"},
      ]
    }
  ];
```

The Model for the JSON file

```
class CarsModel {
  late String make;
  late List<Brand> brand;

  CarsModel({required this.make, required this.brand});

  CarsModel.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    make = json['make'];
    brand = json['brand'].map<Brand>((json) => Brand.fromJSON(json)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['make'] = this.make;
    data['brand'] = this.brand;
    return data;
  }
}

class Brand {
  late String name;
  late String category;

  Brand({required this.name, required this.category});

  Brand.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    category = json['category'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['category'] = this.category;

    return data;
  }
}
```

The Implementation

```
getBrands(String make) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      print('Future.delayed');
    });

    return Future.value(_cars
        .map((map) => CarsModel.fromJSON(map))
        .where((item) => item.make == make)
        .map((e) => e.brand.map((e) => e.name))
        .expand((i) => i)
        .toList());
  }


//My problem is how to get the category based on the brand name selected
 getCategory(String make) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      print('Future.delayed');
    });

    return Future.value(_cars
        .map((map) => Brand.fromJSON(map))
        .where((item) => item.name == make)
        .map((e) => e.category)
        .first
        .toString());
  }


  List<String> getMakes() => _cars
      .map((map) => CarsModel.fromJSON(map))
      .map((item) => item.make)
      .toList();
```

Calling get category

```
category = await getCategory(value);
```

This is the error i get

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to code dropdowns that depend on other dropdowns - using Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62339423/how-to-code-dropdowns-that-depend-on-other-dropdowns-using-flutter)

Comment: YES and NO, I can show the make of the car on the first dropdown and the Model name on the second dropdown. My issue is how to get the category of the car model based on the selected model name from the second dropdown.

Comment: getCategory(String make) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      print('Future.delayed');
    });

    return Future.value(_cars
        .map((map) => Brand.fromJSON(map))
        .where((item) => item.name == make)
        .map((e) => e.category)
        .first
        .toString());
  } 

This is what have been trying to do, to return the category name of the selected brand name.

Comment: I think you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70082828/10157127)

Comment: The way I later solved it was to create a list for the category too. Then create a function to get the index of the selected model name, then get the category item of that index, since the length of both lists will always be equal. Not sure it's the right way, but that's what I came up with and it's working.